# Generate a hashCode from an ArrayList of Objects

Tags: kotlin, hash

I'm trying to generate a hash code from an ArrayList of Objects that would be consistent when executed multiple times. I tried to do an `ArrayList.hashCode()`, but it keeps returning a different value for each execution (since it creates a hash of the memory address). I also tried the `MD5` hash but could not convert it into a `byteArray`.

I'm looking for a reliable and consistent way of hashing other than extracting the strings from the ArrayList iteratively.

Here is how my ArrayList looks like

```kotlin
[[[ObjectClass1, ObjectClass1], ObjectClass2]]

data class class1(
        val a: String,
        val b: String,
        val c: Int,
        val d: class3,
        val e: Boolean
)

data class class3(val a: Set<String>)

enum class class2 { HI, BYE }
```

Here is my code:

```kotlin
class Hasher() {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var toBeHashed

        override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
            return super.equals(other)
        }
        override fun hashCode(): Int {
            // create hash here
            toBeHashed.hashCode()
        }
        fun createHash(arrayList) {
            toBeHashed = arrayList
            val hash = hashCode()
            return hash
        }
    }
}

Hasher.createHash(arrayList)
```

Comment: What is the class of the objects that are inside your arraylist? Please edit the question to add information about the types involved.

Comment: Also, why do you override `equals` and `hashCode` of the companion object of `Hasher`? And does the `Hasher` class contain other things? If it's only a companion object, then probably `Hasher` itself should just be an `object Hasher { ... }` not a regular class.

Comment: Can you turn each object into a byte array? If you can, using `MessageDigest` could be a viable option.

Comment: @Sweeper while this is true, it's likely that the OP just forgot the `hashCode` implementation in one or more classes involved in the structure. In this case, using `MessageDigest` would be quite a convoluted way to fix the problem

Comment: Of course if OP has control over the classes, I'd recommend that too. The question read to me like they do not have control over the classes, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Sweeper @Joffrey I've updated the question with more details about the classes involved. 

@Joffrey Yes `Hasher` class contains other things as well.

Comment: `return CONST + size` (fast hash functions rule!;)

Comment: @xerx593 with `const + size` I would be concerned about a hash collision.

Comment: I think the problem might be the enums here. Their hashcode just calls `System.identityHashcode`. How did you get the list in the first place? Why is it a `List<Any>`? Can you convert the enum values to ints?

Comment: @Sweeper It's an existing code, and I don't think I can make changes to the class. So are you saying it's not possible to do what I'm trying to achieve? :/

Comment: Collision means (with "const hash function"): O(n) "extra effort"...but if you hash function is "clever as hell" (i don't know a way cheaper than O(n)), then why worry about collision/extra effort?? (If every hash takes O(n))

Comment: @xerx593 I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but the main difference is that we calculate a hash only once or from time to time and then comparing int is super fast. `equals()` for the whole object could be very heavy, so we try to avoid doing it.

Comment: (i.m.o. ...javadoc doesn't "postulate" this) Hash-functions *need* to be "constant time" to meet with "hashtable (operations) runtime complexity" ... Of course it is (always) a tradeoff...

Comment: "maintaining a hashcode variable" (similar to `size` (updated on addition/deletion)) seems to be a good way:1. It doesn't ruin `add/delete` complexity (+O(1)) 2. It enables "good hashes" in O(1) time.

Comment: @xerx593 You seem to care about the complexity of the hashCode alone and don't at all care about the performance hit for the whole operation. Simple `hasCode() = 0` is also constant time and it doesn't affect `add/delete`. But well, do as you like.

Answer (score 0):

[`Enum.hashcode`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/30788566012c571aa1d3590912468d1ebe59983d/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Enum.kt#L37) is final, so no enum classes can override it. If your implementation implements it in a execution-inconsistent way, then there's nothing you can do about it.

The only way is to write your own hash code algorithm. For example,

```
fun Enum<*>.consistentHashcode() = 
    this.javaClass.enumConstants.indexOf(this)
    // or name.hashCode()

// you need to write this for the whole list, because ArrayList.hashcode
// calls the built-in hashcode.
fun List<*>.enumConsistentHashcode(): Int {
    var hashCode = 1
    for (i in indices) {
        val e = this[i]
        val eHashCode = when (e) {
            is Enum<*> -> e.consistentHashcode()
            is List<*> -> e.enumConsistentHashcode()
            else -> e.hashCode()
        }
        hashCode = 31 * hashCode + eHashCode
    }
    return hashCode
}
```